# Python Running out of Memory loading images

Tags: python, memory-management, jupyter-notebook, garbage-collection

I have a notebook running inside a docker container on a machine with limited ram, with python 3.6. I am trying to load a large number of images using something like the following code.

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def get_images(self):
       img_list = []
       loop through the contents of folder:
            img = cv2.imread(img_path)
            img = cv2.resize(img, (self.img_size, self.img_size))
            img = img / 255.0
            img = img - np.mean(img)
            img_list.append(img)

       img_list = np.asarray(img_list, dtype = np.float16)
       return img_list
```

I am running out of ram very quickly and the kernel crashes. There is no other code, I narrowed it down to this part that takes up all the ram. Ideally shouldn't the variables be deleted once the function call is finished?

Initially the code looked like this

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def get_images(self):
       img_list = []
       loop through the contents of folder:
            img = cv2.imread(img_path)
            img = cv2.resize(img, (self.img_size, self.img_size))
            img - np.array(img) / 255.0
            img = img - np.mean(img)
            img_list.append(img)

       return np.array(img_list)
```

But I saw using debugger the **list** created by this part of the code takes up too much memory and even after the function returns the numpy array, `img_list` variable is taking up space in the memory, so I assigned the **numpy array** to the name `img_list`, hoping that it would remove the reference to the **list**. Also I changed `np.array` to `np.asarray` to convert it into a numpy array inplace instead of creating a copy. I also changed the dtype to `np.float16`.
After assigning the name `img_list` to the **numpy array**, the original **list** does not show up in debugger anymore, but the amount memory consumed remains the same.

I checked the size of the returned numpy array and it is 1 GB, but this small function call takes up 6 GB of my memory and that memory is not being freed even after I manually call garbage collector using `gc.collect()`.

I am running it on jupyter lab if that is relevant. I have looked everywhere and according to all the answers calling garbage collector manually is not necessary in most cases as pythons garbage collection is reliable. And if it has to be called, calling it should solve all the issues. But for me it doesn't do anything at all. It shows a number of garbage is deleted, but that doesn't free up the ram at all, or even if it does it's negligible.

Comment: Have you tried using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()`?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a simplified version of the code, the dataloader I have loads 4 types of images from 4 different folders and also their corresponding time series data from csv files and creates an object. So I think that would not work. I simplified the code down to this for locating the problem.